# Which is the best way to use media player?

Tags: java, android, media-player

Just to be clear, because my question can be not so clear.

I develop **Music Player** app. The thing is I have **MainActivity** and 4 **Fragments** in this activity(it's not all).

In each fragment I have list of songs retrieved from device using CustomCursorAdapter(for example: first fragment - all songs, second fragment albums e.t.c.)

I already tried to use **MediaPlayerSingleton**

```
public class singletonMediaPlayer{

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private static singletonMediaPlayer in = null;
    private singletonMediaPlayer() { }

    public static singletonMediaPlayergetInstance() {
        if (in == null) {
            synchronized (singletonMediaPlayer.class) {
                if (in == null) {
                    in = new singletonMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

But here the problem was that all playback controls I have in MainActivity(not in fragments) and have no idea how to handle previouse, next buttons. It is not a problem if media player is in fragment or activity together with ListView of songs but like this... have no idea. Plus when I tried to select item(song) from another activity it just didn't play until I press play button. Playbacks I can see it through all fragments so it's looks like this(just in case):

[image: As you can see down there]

Plus I have 2 seperate **Activities** to show songs from albums and from playlists. Sooooooooooo... Finaly the question is:
How do you think it is better to build Media Player for such app (just in case, I don't need code from you). Is it better to use Music Service(which I already started to build) or maybe Singletone is better(in that case I just don't know how to perform the task with singletone for now) or **maybe** there is another way??? Will be great if somebody response with hint, link or just show me the way in which better to go.

Thank you in advance!

**P.S.**
Yep, by the way there are 3 ListViews with songs(for now) - 2 of them reusable.

Comment: You should probably watch the [Best Practices in Media Playback I/O 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKxyDRjecU) first of all.

Comment: Thank you, I quite new in here so didn't know about such things. Thank you)

Comment: As it is now, this question is too broad to be answered in just a few paragraphs **and** asking for offsite resources is also off topic for StackOverflow. I'd suggest posting more general architectural questions on a separate forum (such as the [Android Development Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/105153134372062985968).

Comment: Ok, thanks, by the way thank you for the link. Really usefull info.